# Numbers expressed by a ratio of square roots

Tags: elementary-set-theory, radicals

Let's $\mathbb{S}$ the set of numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ that can be expressed by :

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \: \text{or}\: -\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

What numbers fall in this category ?

For example for $n_1$ in $\mathbb{N}$ :

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{1}$$

for $n_2 < 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ :

$$n=-\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{1}$$

for $\frac{p}{q}         $ in $\mathbb{Q}$ :

$$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{\sqrt{p^2}}{\sqrt{q^2}}$$

for $\frac{p}{q} \lt 0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ :

$$\frac{p}{q} = -\frac{\sqrt{p^2}}{\sqrt{q^2}}$$

But what other combinations of addition, multiplication and radicals, can be expressed as this ?

For example is the golden ratio in $\mathbb{S}$ ?

Comment: $x\in \mathbb{S} \iff x^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Take the golden ratio $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. As @DanielFischer said, this will be in $\mathbb{S}$ if and only if $\varphi^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. So we calculate $\varphi^2 = \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt{5} + 5}{4} = \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Suppose this were rational, then for some integers $p,q$ we would have $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. But then $\sqrt{5} = 2\frac{p}{q} - 3$. Because the RHS is rational, $\sqrt{5}$ is then rational. Since this is not true, $\varphi \notin \mathbb{S}$.